# SharePoint servers moving to a different data center

Tags: server

our SharePoint 2010 and 2013 farms are moving to a different data server (actually AWS). Is there any checklist or excel script that I can use to verify that all functions are working properly? (for example, SSL, Email like when you add someone they get an email, DNS, User Profile Syncs). I really really need this. Can anyone share if you already have one? I can't think off all the stuff I need to verify after the lift/shift.

Comment: So far I noticed smtp related task aren't working (workflow sending email), OWA is not working, Excel services are not working, What else ? It's hard to find what's not working. Do anyone have a list of things that i can go through easily ?